# Why use resistor in series with coincell for RTC backup power?

Tags: power, batteries

I've noticed a lot of reference designs use a resistor in series with the coincell supplying power to a backup RTC. For example, see R141 on Varicite's sheet 8 of the [schematic for the carrier board for their DART 8M SOM](https://www.variscite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/VAR-DT8MCustomBoard-Schematics.pdf):
[image: Example of circuit with resistor in series with coincell]

Why is this? Is it some sort of ESD protection for when the cell is plugged in?

More importantly, how do I know when I need one and how should I size the resistor?

Comment: this site requires a reference to any included material... please add a link to the source of the schematic diagram ... add to the question ... **do not** write a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is for safety approvals when using lithium coin cells.

Even if it wasn't for the regulations, this design uses a Schottky diode for low forward voltage drop, but Schottky diodes leak current backwards when reverse biased. Not much in itself, but significantly more than regular diodes. And lithium coin cells do not tolerate much charging current at all.

So when main supply is on, the resistor is there to limit any leakage current that can charge the non-chargeable battery to safe level so that it does not degrade or damage.

The regulations require also two levels of safety if one fails short. If the resistor or diode turns into a short circuit, there is still one component left to prevent a total short circuit of the battery to supply voltage that would charge it at high current.

Usually RTC datasheets and application notes tell you how to connect the battery properly. Some are e.g. UL rated for direct battery connection as they have internal protections, some are not rated and then external components are required (there may be internal protection, but e.g. UL approval has not been applied for so there can be no approvals).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I've looked at datasheets for a handful of 16mm coin cells on DigiKey but none specify anything like a "max tolerated input current" for the cell. I'm assuming I would size the resistor off such a value if one was provided. Since I haven't been able to find an input current spec, would you say that the 2.2k used by Varisicite is a reasonable best guess at a current limit resistor?

Comment: @oneil Not many batteries list that. Safety approval agencies might have a formula for safe values that depend on exact chemistry type and cell capacity guaranteed not to cause problems. And if the device does not need much current the value can be higher than required by safety agencies.